# EndsWith in Javascript for Validation Form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a question. How to do a validation form in javascript that the condition is "Must be ended with 'City'"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example i have to taken to make you understand about the [endsWith()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_endswith.asp) method.

```js
function myFunction2() {
    var str = "This is City but I am not there";
    var n = str.endsWith("City");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = n;
}

function myFunction() {
    var str = "Welcome to my City";
    var n = str.endsWith("City");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = n;
}

function validate(){
   var txtdata = document.getElementById("city").value;
   var txtdata = txtdata.endsWith("City");
   if(txtdata){
      document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "City Found at end";
   }else{
      document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Must be ended with City";
   }
    
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check its working with City</button>

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Check its working without City</button>

<div id="result"></div>

<!-- Validate in form data -->
<form>
   <input type="text" id="city" name="city"/>
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<div id="result2"></div>
```

In the similar way you have to take input from form store it in a variable do validation.